# Android notification with Serializable payload

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have an Android app with a single activity and use FCM for messaging. In an `onMessageReceived` I prepare a PendingIntent to start the activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(KEY, mySerializableObject)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
```

where `mySerializableObject` is an instance of the `MySerializableClass` which implements the `Serializable` interface. The members of the class are taken from the data payload of the FCM message:

```
val a = remoteMessage.data[KEY_A]
val b = remoteMessage.data[KEY_B]
val mySerializableObject = MySerializableClass(a, b)
```

In `onResume` of the activity I want to restore `mySerializableObject`:

```
val serializable = intent.getSerializableExtra(KEY)
```

If the activity is in the foreground then `serializable` is `not null` and can be cast to `MySerializableClass`.

However, if the activity is in the background then `serializable` is `null`. It turns out that `intent.extras` include the data members of FCM message:

```
val a1 = extras.getString(KEY_A)
val b1 = extras.getString(KEY_B)
```

As far as I can see the above PendingIntent is unrelated to the FCM data. How can the notification include the data fields nevertheless?

Can you please explain what happens here, why do the `intent.extras` have different payload from the same source depending on the foreground / background state?